# Why is only the default controller works in CodeIgniter on localhost WAMP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, wamp

When click on default controller it redirects to `localhost/foldername/controller/function` but when I click on other menu items it does not redirect properly.

It redirects to `localhost/function_name` and thereby showing:

> "The requested URL was not found on this server".

Comment: Have you added an htaccess file?

Comment: You probably removed the index.php in your code, but there's no htaccess to handle that. Make sure you have the htaccess to handle that or just go into your config/config.php and add the index.php as the index page.

Comment: i think .htaccess file is missing in your public directory